# Field calculator or update cursor?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, field-calculator, cursor

I have a feature class in which one field (let's call it "Field_A"), as yet empty, is to be populated by the contents of another field ("Field_B") multiplied by a certain number (I'll call it the "constant"). Would it be a good idea to simply populate Field_A using an update cursor, as follows:

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(InTable) 
for row in rows:
     row.Field_A = row.Field_B * constant
     rows.updateRow(row) 
del row, rows
```

, or do I have to use the field calculator? If I have to use the field calculator, I'm having an issue with the syntax. I defined the expression thus:

`expression = "Field_A * constant"`

and the code is as follows:

`arcpy.CalculateField_management(InTable, "Field_A", expression)`

When using CalculateField as shown, the script runs without errors, but "Field_A" is populated with zeros as a result. What am I doing wrong with CalculateField, or should I simply use an update cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could go either way with this code.  Your first code block would run correctly.
I imagine there are some speed differences between looping through rows and doing a calculate values, so the latter is probably much faster.

Try this for the `field calculator` expression:

```
expression = "!Field_B! * constant"

arcpy.CalculateField_management(InTable, "Field_A", expression, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

You did not have the required field delimiter for the field name in the expression string.  Fields have to be wrapped with a "!", just like they would appear in the Field Calculator window in ArcMap when using a python expression.  Also note that I added `PYTHON_9.3` to the end, which will invoke the more current version of the geoprocessor.  Read the [Calculate Field (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000) help entry, for more information.

Here is a screenshot of the Field Calculator window for reference:
[image: Field Calculator Window]

Comment: Although this option makes sense, a field name does not have to be wrapped with a "!" in order for the field calculator python method to work correctly within a python script.

Comment: @artwork21 - Based on the help document, in the `Expression` block, every time a field name is referenced, it is wrapped in "!", so that is what I went by.

Comment: Thanks! I used the field calculator, with exclamation marks and the expression type, and everything worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question you want to multiple values from field B not field A.  Your expression should be:

```
expression = "Field_B * constant"
```